How to identify parametric model of a buck converter?
I have a buck dc-dc converter

My goal is to identify a dynamic model of this circuit. The model shall serve for design of the inductor current control loop. Until this moment I thought the model in following form (deviation model comming from linearization of the first order differential equation in a given steady state operating point \$E_0, d_0, i_{{L}_0}\$ in cascade with a transport delay modeling the pwm modulator and a low pass filter modeling the analog channel including the current sensor dynamic)

As far as the model identification (determination of the unknown parameters \$T_d, R_L, L, T\$) I have chosen a very simple approach. I have applied a step change of the duty cycle and recorded the system response i.e. the inductor current \$i_L\$. The step response I have got is below

along with the voltage conditions during the identification experiment

Later I have found that the identification method I have chosen has a serious weakness namely the step response is influenced by the input voltage fluctuation (a sixth harmonic of the \$50\,\mathrm{Hz}\$ grid). This can be observed in the zoomed records of the voltages

and step response

My question is whether it is possible to use the step response distorted by the disturbance (after some preprocessing) for system identification or shall I use different approach? Thanks in advance for your opinion.

Why not use a proper simulation of your full circuit?
